# DOM contenteditable selecting parent node

Tags: html, dom

I have the following code:

```
<span class="outside">
    <span class="before">...</span>
    <span class="edit" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off"
    autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">TEXT</span>
    <span class="after">...</span>
</span>
<style>
    .outside {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is, if I select the whole text in the "edit" span, as in Ctrl + A, Ctrl + X, Ctrl + V, then the result pasted into the "edit" span will be:

```
<span class="outside">
    <span class="edit" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off"
    autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">TEXT
    </span>
</span>
```

and not just the textnode "TEXT". I thought that the style would prevent the parent to be selected, but it seems to be ignored. By the way, if I select only parts of the "edit" span, the same problem shows up, just only for the copied and pasted part. It is too complicated to discribe it here, but I think you understand what I mean. How can I prevent the selection of the parent node? And in fact the "edit" node itself too should not be selected. Only the text.

Comment: Do I have to use an <input type="text"> field? Probably the only solution. But then I have to add Javascript to keep the width relative to the width of the content. Using user-select: text; on the "edit" span doesn:t help. I'm testing it with the latest firefox on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Can't reproduce [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u63d9xdr/)